# How can I make a security token automatically expire in a passive STS setup?

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, wif, passive-sts

I have a passive STS set up for a new application I'm working on.

I've noticed that when a user's session expires, the user is still authenticated.  I would have thought that when the session expires, the user would no longer be authenticated.  My boss discussed this with me as I am currently charged with setting up the authentication.  He says that it would be good if we could make the user's log on expire after a certain period of inactivity similar to how the session expires.

I am familiar with how to sign a user out with a few lines of code.  How can I make it so that the user is automatically signed out after a specified period of inactivity?

Currently, I have some code in the `global.asax` file that programmatically checks when the last request was and compares it to the current time; it then signs the user out if a certain period of time has expired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peter Kron has proposed an answer in your MSDN thread:

> Handle the SessionSecurityTokenCreated event raised by WSFederationAuthenticationModule. In that you can create a new SessionSecurityToken from the proposed token, and set the lifetime as you please.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Geneva/thread/6b6d51ea-9c15-4744-800b-dd1379b495c3

Comment: With so many things on my plate, I had actually forgotten that I started that thread.  Thanks!

Comment: You must also put `e.ReissueCookie  =  true` in the handler method or else it won't work :-/

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have wired in the same, but the "Created" event DOES NOT HAVE a `"e.ReissueCookie"` property, and I keep reading how critical this is. My expiration is getting set correctly, but I'm still authenticated well beyond the expiration date.