# Sliding Expiration in ASP.NET web app using claims from STS

Tags: asp.net, wif, claims-based-identity, passive-sts

Two questions:

1) How/where do I set the lifetime of the session cookie in my web application when using an STS to get claims? From what I can tell, it seems I can only do this programmatically in the ServiceConfigurationCreated event.

2) How/where can I make sure that the expiration is sliding?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967253/how-can-i-make-a-security-token-automatically-expire-in-a-passive-sts-setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StsDude, I asked your question here: [How can I make a security token automatically expire in a passive STS setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967253/how-can-i-make-a-security-token-automatically-expire-in-a-passive-sts-setup)

A code sample for the answer may be found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Geneva/thread/a048694c-3548-4b4d-9bb3-0589c888fd02